# Trim subsections length in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I would like to trim subsections length in my table of contents despite of the title of subsection will be so long. Something like in this pic, I mean, trim this reference but keeping my subsection without changes.

[image]

Produced by this code:

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{blablablablablablablablabla}
\subsection{blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla}

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much! :D

Comment: Please include a minimum working example of the code in question.  See this Meta post if in doubt: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Comment: Just use `\subsection[<ToC title>]{<regular title>}`.